# Error: Invalid `prisma.userApiLimit.findUnique()` invocation:

Tags: typescript, database, next.js, prisma

Getting error in my lib\api-limit.ts.
Code:
Its shoowing error in this line  `const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique`, plzz let me
know where am i going wrong.

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { MAX_FREE_COUNTS } from "@/constants";

export const incrementApiLimit = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: { userId: userId },
  });

  if (userApiLimit) {
    await prismadb.userApiLimit.update({
      where: { userId: userId },
      data: { count: userApiLimit.count + 1 },
    });
  } else {
    await prismadb.userApiLimit.create({
      data: { userId: userId, count: 1 },
    });
  }
};

export const checkApiLimit = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return false;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: { userId: userId },
  });

  if (!userApiLimit || userApiLimit.count < MAX_FREE_COUNTS) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

export const getApiLimitCount = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) {
    return 0;
  }

  const userApiLimit = await prismadb.userApiLimit.findUnique({
    where: {
      userId
    }
  });

  if (!userApiLimit) {
    return 0;
  }

  return userApiLimit.count;
};
```

I was trying to use prisma for fetching data but getting error here:

Error:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.userApiLimit.findUnique()` invocation:


Error querying the database: Server error: `ERROR HY000 (1105): unavailable: unable to connect to branch 8yeh0d8jjckc'
```